# Javascript Closure : How does it remember the environment?

Tags: javascript, closures

1.) A **closure** is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the **environment** in which that function was created. The **environment** consists of any **local variables** that were in-scope at the time that the closure was created

2.) The function defined in the closure **'remembers' the environment** in which it was created.

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

My **question** is **how** does the **closure remembers the environment** in which it was created ( I mean it must be saved somewhere, but how and where ?? ).

and further more if have a **modular pattern** ( which makes use of closure to emulate private and public scope ) like this

```
var Module = (function () {
  var privateMethod = function () {

  };
  return {
    publicMethod1: function () {
      // has access to `privateMethod`, we can call it:
      // privateMethod();
    },
    publicMethod2 : function(){
      //another public method
    }

  };
})();
```

so in this do **both publicmethod1 and publicmethod2** in above case **remember the whole environment** ??

Comment: what do you mean "remember the **whole** environment"?

Comment: Memory is allocated when a function is called, and a reference to it is retained as part of the implementation of the closure. It's just an object.

Comment: If by remembering the whole enviroment you mean has access to variables declared in it's scope, then yes. Exactly how the implementation does it is irrelevant.

Comment: i mean all the functions and variables defined the in the module pattern scope!!

Comment: It may be helpful to review [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) mdn article if you are struggling with scope in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how does the closure remembers the environment in which it was created ( I mean it must be saved somewhere, but how and where ?? ).

It's part of the function object created for the closure. A property (that you can't access) that has a reference to what the spec calls the *binding object* of the *execution context* in which the function was created. That binding object is where all of the variables (and other variable-like things, such as function arguments) that are in scope for that specific execution context (that call to the containing function) are held.

The binding object has a reference to the binding object of the enviroment that contains *it*, as well; this is loosely called the "scope chain".

When you look up a variable reference, the engine first looks at the binding object at the beginning (innermost) scope. If it has the variable, it gets used; if not, the next binding object out is used, and so on until we reach global scope.

More *(on my blog)*: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

> ...does both publicmethod1 and publicmethod2 in above case remember the whole environment ??

They both have references to the same binding object, the one created by calling your anonymous function. Assuming that code appears at global scope, that one binding object has a reference to the global binding object. (Which is the only binding object we can directly access: It's the global object, accessible as `this` in the global context, as `this` in non-strict code called without an explicit `this`, and via the global variable `window` on browsers.)

Some ASCII-Art:

```
      +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      |                                                                                       |
      v                                                                                       |
+---------------+                                                                             |
| global object |                                                                             |
+---------------+     +---------------+                                                       |
| Module        |---->|    Object     |                                                       |
| ...           |     +---------------+     +-------------+                                   |
+---------------+     | publicMethod1 |---->|   Function  |                                   |
                      | publicMethod1 |--+  +-------------+                                   |
                      +---------------+  |  | (reference) |--+                                |
                                         |  +-------------+  |                                |
                                         |                   |                                |
                                         |                   |    +------------------------+  |
                                         |                   +-+->| DeclarativeEnvironment |  |
                                         |  +-------------+  | |  +------------------------+  |
                                         +->|   Function  |  | |  | (scope chain link)     |--+  +-------------+
                                            +-------------+  | |  | privateMethod          |---->|   Function  |
                                            | (reference) |--+ |  +------------------------+     +-------------+
                                            +-------------+    |                                 | (reference) |--+
                                                               |                                 +-------------+  |
                                                               |                                                  |
                                                               +--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation...I was just concerned that if have a large number of public method like the two above and each of them has a own copy of the environment...then it might take a toll on the memory..

Comment: @bhavya_w: Don't worry, it's not a *copy*, it's a *reference*.